# jquery menu slides in and bounces

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

http://jsfiddle.net/E6cUF/

The idea is that after the page finished loading the grey box slides left from behind the green box, if possible bounce a little.

Edit: made a new version based on changes people made to the jsfiddle and the comment from Nicola
http://jsfiddle.net/RBD3K/

However the grey one should be behind the green one and slide from right to left so it appears

Comment: do you want the right to change width during it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have it bounce you are missing two things i think:

1) you need to load jquery UI.

2) put the bounce effect after the animate effect:

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    var $marginLefty = $('.left');
    $marginLefty.animate({
      marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'),10) == 0 ?
        $marginLefty.outerWidth() :
        0
    }).effect("bounce", { times:5 }, 300);
  });
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/E6cUF/4/

Comment: Exactly like that, but then on the left side with a little bit of space between them, and after the page has loaded.
I tried myself a little, it bounces now after load but the grey div must be on the left and with 10px space between the grey and green div http://jsfiddle.net/RBD3K/5/ Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this . Not sure if this is what you want.

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    var $marginLefty = $('.left');
    var $marginRight = $('.right');
    $marginLefty.animate({
      marginLeft: 0
    },{ duration: 200, queue: false });
    $marginRight.animate({
      marginLeft: 100
    },{ duration: 200, queue: false });
  });
```

Update: from your updated fiddle,add for .right  `position :absolute;z-index:1000` as css

http://jsfiddle.net/E6cUF/11/